# How to return multiple types of objects array from Json Format WCF service?

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a wcf application that helps mobile to sync. However, I could now return multiple type of objects from one single method.

What I did was create a object call sync objects and add all objects to the sync objects array and then serialise it. The following would show the class.

```
[DataContract]
    public class CSyncObjects
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string DataType { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public object DataObject { get; set; }

        public CSyncObjects(string Type, object Object)
        {
            this.DataType = Type;
            this.DataObject = Object;
        }
    }
```

However, whenever I try to access it by url I get the following error ERR_CONNECTION_RESET error on Chrome. What should I do?

Comment: I had the same issue but I just every type to separate method

Comment: You may be running into trouble because WCF doesn't know how to serialize object. It needs a known type that is serializable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a tuple, to return multiple stuff in the same method.

```
Tuple<int, string, bool> tuple = new Tuple<int, string, bool>(1, "dog", true);
return tuple;
```

Comment: Your idea is great but there is a problem. Will there be any redundant information? cause every attribute is not filled

Answer (score 0):

Passing an instance of type system.object across the service boundary is both nonsensical and breaks [tenet one](http://architectopia.blogspot.co.uk/2008/01/four-tenets-of-soa.html) of SOA: *Boundaries are explicit*.

If you need to be able to pass multiple types, then WCF provides the [ServiceKnownType attribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.serviceknowntypeattribute(v=vs.110).aspx), which gives you a way to treat instances of multiple types polymorphically over the service boundary.

Simply create a base class to represent the operation argument, and then decorate the service interface definition with the supported derived types via ServiceKnownType attribute:

```
[ServiceContract]
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(RoadBike))]
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(AllTerrianBike))]
public Interface IBikeStoreFront
{
     [OperationContract]
     Bicycle GetBike(int bikeId);

     [OperationContract]
     void UpdateBike(Bicycle bike);  
} 

[DataContract]
public class Bicycle 
{
}

[DataContract]
public class RoadBike : Bicycle
{
}

[DataContract]
public class AllTerrianBike : Bicycle
{
}
```